# Trying to get unique weight and height of players from each unique year in SQL

Tags: sql

[image]
This is the question.

Display the average weight and height of the Mariners (SEA) for each year they played.
Include the year, average weight, and average height in year order starting with the most
recent year

```
SELECT yearID, AVG(weight) as AverageWeight, AVG(height) as AverageHeight
FROM [TWalls_W23].[dbo].[PlayersAndTeams]
where teamID = 'SEA' 
group by yearID
```

I've written that above but it's not showing me the average weight or height from each unique year.

Comment: It doesn't? What do you get? A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY` to ensure _starting with the most recent year_.

Comment: It returns an average weight of 187 and average height of 72 for each year. I tried adding the ORDER BY yearID but I still get the same results

Comment: Have you mixed up the column names or units? 187 cm and 72 kg / 187 lb and 72 inches?

Comment: I double checked and I don't believe so. It's 187lb and 72 inches.

Comment: I added a link to a screen shot

Comment: Can you share some sample data, the result you're getting and the result you're trying to get for that sample?

Comment: Also, is it possible that that team hasn't changed over the years?

Comment: I thought about that but I don't think its possible. It's 1977 to 2021. So the team would have gotten new players in that amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast to decimal.

```
SELECT yearID, AVG(CAST(weight as DECIMAL)) as AverageWeight, AVG(CAST(height AS DECIMAL)) as AverageHeight
FROM [TWalls_W23].[dbo].[PlayersAndTeams]
where teamID = 'SEA' 
group by yearID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is ok, so your problem come from your data.